# Display text instead of ID in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a table that includes integers that are ids linking to another table. For example, one field may be called StatusId, has a value of 4 and looks at tblStatuses to find the matching record.

I created a WPF DataGrid to put this data into, all working.

I created a CollectionViewSource to store the records from tblStatuses, all working.

I created a CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate to show the field and when editing, show a dropdown with the current status which can then be changed. All working.

Where I am now stuck is to show the current status in its lookup text value in the column in the celltemplate, instead of just the id. i.e. display 'Current' instead of 4.

I have tried using the same ComboBox method in CellTemplate and modifying the ComboBox Template to show a label but it shows the wrong value. I'm not sure what else to try at the moment and google/so aren't helping, mostly because this is a difficult one to search.

```
<DataGrid Name="grdLearners" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Surname" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusID}"></TextBlock> // displays id i.e. 4, need to display text i.e. 'Current'
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StatusID}" SelectedValuePath="Status_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusesList}}"></ComboBox> // displays list of statuses and correctly shows/sets the id in the row
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Hoping someone can shed some light on this or point me in the right direction. Let me know if you need any other code posted.

[image: CellEditingTemplate]

Code for Collection

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusesList"  CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Code-behind for setting data/collection:

```
AppDb db = new AppDb();
var learners = db.Learners.AsNoTracking().Take(40).ToList();            

var stats = db.StudentStatuses.AsNoTracking().ToList();

CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("StatusesList"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = stats;

var grid = grdLearners as DataGrid;
grid.ItemsSource = learners;
```

Comment: How is the `StatusID` property supposed to return a `string`? You don't store the selected string in the data object, you only store the id.

Comment: If you look at the ComboBox, I have a CollectionViewSource on the window that is storing all the statuses, i.e. 1 - New, 2 - Pending etc. This ComboBox correctly shows the text value based on the StatusID property. I want to display the matching text in the standard cell template, not just the editing one. I know the textblock won't do this I've just posted how it is currently displaying the ID. I tried using a ComboBox in the same manner in celltemplate but the displayed value is wrong for some reason.

Comment: Does your data object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, to clarify I have also posted code-behind for setting data in grid and collection

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the text, you should store it in your data object. You are currently only storing the id in the `StatusID` property. If you add a `Status` property to your data object, you could bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate` to this one:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status.Status}"/>
...
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Status}" DisplayMemberPath="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusesList}}" />
```

If you don't want to add another property to your data object, you could use a converter that looks up the value in the `StatusesList`:

```
public class StatusConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int statusId = (int)values[0];
        IEnumerable<TheStatus> statuses = (IEnumerable<TheStatus>)values[1];

        return statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status_ID == statusId)?.Status;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:StatusConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="StatusID" />
                        <Binding Path="SourceCollection" Source="{StaticResource StatusesList}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StatusID}" SelectedValuePath="Status_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Status" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusesList}}"></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note that you need to change `TheStatus` to whatever the name of your status type is in the converter.

Comment: Yes, my issue with that was if putting the text in the object, when updating the dropdown, the text would be incorrect. I will try the converter as this should let me do a direct lookup for the text, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Simple method without complex functions if you are loading data from Database,use INNER JOINT

SELECT table1.id,....,tblStatuses.Status (if table1 has same column 'Status'then use 
"tblStatuses.Status as Stat1")
FROM table1
INNER JOIN tblStatuses
ON table1.StatusId = tblStatuses.Id;

//Directly use binding in .xaml (or Stat1 if 'as'used)
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Status}" SelectedValuePath="Status_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Status" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusesList}}">
```